# Executar um FOR no Webbrowser C#

Tags: c#, winforms, navegador-de-internet

No momento estou tentando desenvolver uma aplicação de captura de dados usando o `WebBrowser` do C#. Eu consigo fazer a aplicação entrar na página e informar o valor e clicar em pesquisa, porém, não consigo atrelar essa função ao laço `for`, para que o mesmo seja executado repetidamente! Gostaria de saber como faço. Abaixo segue um exemplo do código que tenho:

```
 private void BTN_OPEMIE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            navegar();

            insert();

            BtnPesq();
    }

    public void navegar()
    {
        wb_1.Navigate("http://www3.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/smt/pesqveic/Pesquisa.aspx");

        while (wb_1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }

    }

    public void insert()
    {
        wb_1.Document.GetElementById("txtplaca").SetAttribute("value", "ASD7534");

        wb_1.Document.GetElementById("btnPesquisar").InvokeMember("Click");


    }

    public void BtnPesq()
    {
        wb_1.Document.GetElementById("btnPesquisar").InvokeMember("Click");

        while (wb_1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();

        }

    }
```

O `for` seria nesta etapa do código:

```
 private void BTN_OPEMIE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
        navegar();

        insert();

        BtnPesq();
      }
}
```

Comment: Por que não tá dando certo?

Comment: Então, eu coloquei todos os comandos de navegação do webBrowser, dentro de uma laço for, e o mesmo não esta executando as etapas correspondentes, ou seja, no primeiro loop ele deve fazer uma pesquisa, no próximos também e assim sucessivamente. O que ocorre, é que ele esta pulando as etapas, ou seja ele só faz a 1ª consulta e as demais não.